# How to read a checkbox's @onclick event after the value

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

when I use a function in `@onclick` for a checkbox and check the input of `@bind-Value` the returned value is different, it looks like `@onclick` event is executed first than @bind-Value

follow the example

```
<div>
    <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@testCheck" Color="Color.Secondary" @onclick="()=> ChecktestBox()"></MudCheckBox>
    <p>Value: @testCheck</p>
</div>

@code {
    private bool testCheck { get; set; } = false;
    
    private void ChecktestBox() {
        MessageBox.Show(testCheck.ToString());
        
        if(testCheck)
            ....
    }
}
```

The result is that the function added in the @onclick event even if the value is true returns false

and in the message used `Value: @testCheck` returns the value correctly

What should I do, from the correct `@testCheck` value

Comment: Not too familiar with MudBlazor but there are several events going on.   The Blazor bind process binds to `onchange` which actually updates the value of  `TestCheck`.  I don't have mudblazor installed to check the order of execution, but I'm guessing `onclick` executes before `onchange`.  If you want an event when `testCheck` changes then put it in `testCheck`s setter.

Comment: You could also try the `oninput` event.  It probably works on a checkbox and returns the new value, but I haven't tested it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Mud CheckBox is successfully binding to the boolean, then you could use a custom `get; set;` for it.  However, be careful what you do with that-- you probably don't want to call an involved `async Task` with it.

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind="CheckTest"/>
@Message

@code {
    string Message;

    private bool _checkTest;
    bool CheckTest
    {
        get { return _checkTest; }
        set { _checkTest = value; HandleCheck(value);  }
    }

    void HandleCheck(bool IsChecked)
    {
        Message = IsChecked ? "Do something" : "Don't do the thing";
    }
}
```

I find it a little hard to believe, though, that the Mud Checkbox wouldn't correctly handle `@onchange`.

Comment: interesting methodology seems to work now.

I also don't like using third-party components, but some things I like the style of the material web of google, I even thought of using the web stuff directly instead of some third-party one, but I didn't find anything talking about the  support the material web of google for blazor

Comment: @Brian Brince I recommend taking the .css or other style ideas that you like, and just make a Component of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MudCheckBox, but I can say that in my normal practice, there's no point 2-way binding to the Value or Checked property of a checkbox.  That's because the onchange event Value delivers that property.  You have to cast ChangeEventArgs to read the value if it's not a string.

```
<input type="checkbox" @onchange="HandleCheck" />
@Message

@code {
    string Message;

    void HandleCheck(ChangeEventArgs arg)
    {
        bool IsChecked = (bool)arg.Value;
        Message = IsChecked ? "Use this value" : "Don't use this value";
    }
}
```

I'd normally only use 2-way binding if I had a bool property in a class that I wanted to set.

Comment: Using input works but using Mud CheckBox doesn't work

Comment: I very strongly dislike using 3rd-party components.  It's so easy in Blazor to make a custom checkbox (for example) of my own, that unless it's something very complex (like an HTML editor) it's just not worth the time figuring out how other people's stuff works.  It's also annoying on SO, because I have to install the library in order to see what the problem is or to try and help you.  That being said. . . I'll try another method.